# How to play Youtube Video in my app without using Webview

Tags: android, webview

I cant use WebView, please help me

I  will try my best & I hope I can solve it here.

Answer (score 0):

check out official release of [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player), which plays yt videos natively, without any web-side

and if you want/need web player, but you can't use `WebView` - you may implement "FirefoxView", web engine used by Mozilla in their Android software, not related to Chromium at all, called [`GeckoView`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lib from opensource: [link](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)